# how to use jsp variable in struts 2 tag

Tags: struts2

I am wondering if there is any way to use jsp variable in struts 2 tags.

I tried as given below but i did not work.

Suggest me if there is any way to do this.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<% for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   { 
%>

   <s:textarea name=%{i} value=%{i}></s:textarea>
<%}%>
```

please help me.

Comment: Can any one provide me code for this using struts 2 tags

Comment: You can't. The struts tags read values off of the ValueStack. Use the s:iterator tag as others have suggested or use the c:forEach tag if you want to use JSP EL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any question involving struts2 tags please see: https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/tag-reference.html

Note the begin and end properties as follows

```
<s:iterator var="counter" begin="0" end="9" >
   <s:textfield name="%{#counter}" value="%{#counter}" /><br/>
</s:iterator>
```

will produce the desired result.

**Edit**: just reading your comment to leonbloy you would not use the above, but rather iterate over the collection. Provide a getter which returns your collection. ie:

```
   public List<String> getCollection(){return this.collection};
```

Then in the jsp you would write:

```
<s:iterator value="collection">
   <s:property/><br/>
</s:iterator>
```

The above will print out all the strings in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
<s:property value="%{#i}" />
```

Read the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/jsp.html). BTW, that code smells bad, you should try to not mix struts2 tags with JSP Scriptlets (in general -struts2 or anything- you'd try to avoid  JSP Scriptlets `<% ...  %>` as much as possible.). Read about the [iterator](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/iterator.html) tag.

Comment: I am reading values from database.Those values should be displayed in textarea.Number of textarea's are not fixed.Just for simplicity i wrote for loop.